How can I use he following similarity transformation in this pde to get to the equation in the image?
I don't know how to get from equation 1.20 to equation 1.21



I tried to use the chain rule for partial derivatives. If $f = f(x,t)$, I wrote:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^3} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}$
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}$
$\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^3} = \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial \xi^3} \frac{\partial^3 \xi}{\partial x^3} = 0$, since $\frac{\partial^3 \xi}{\partial x^3} = 0$ because $\xi = \frac{x}{\varepsilon}$
when I plug it at equation 1.20, I get:
$\frac{1}{\varepsilon^3} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau} + \alpha f^m \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} = 0$
What am I missing?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.


$\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^3} = \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial \xi^3} \frac{\partial^3 \xi}{\partial x^3} = 0$, since $\frac{\partial^3 \xi}{\partial x^3} = 0$ because $\xi = \frac{x}{\varepsilon}$

That's not how the chain rule works for a triple integral, which is not a cubic product, but three applications of the operator.
Fortunately, since $\tfrac{\partial\xi}{\partial x}$ is a constant ($\varepsilon^{-1}$), this one is quite easy.
$\qquad\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial^3 ~~}{\partial x~^3} &= \left(\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\right)\!\left(\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\right)\!\left(\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\right)\\[1ex] &=\left(\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial ~}{\partial \xi}\right)\!\left(\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial ~}{\partial \xi}\right)\!\left(\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial ~}{\partial \xi}\right)\\[1ex]&=\left(\varepsilon^{-1}\cdot\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial \xi}\right)\!\left(\varepsilon^{-1}\cdot\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial \xi}\right)\!\left(\varepsilon^{-1}\cdot\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial \xi}\right)\\[1ex]&=\left(\varepsilon^{-1}\cdot\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial \xi}\right)\!\left(\varepsilon^{-2}\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2~~}{\partial \xi~^2}\right)\\[1ex] &= \varepsilon^{-3}\dfrac{\partial^3~~}{\partial \xi~^3}\end{align}$
So we obtain:$$\left(\varepsilon^{-3}\frac{\partial ~~}{\partial \tau} + \varepsilon^{-1}\alpha f^m  \frac{\partial ~~}{\partial \xi} + \varepsilon^{-3} \delta \dfrac{\partial^3~~}{\partial \xi~^3}\right) f(\varepsilon\xi,\varepsilon^3\tau)= 0$$
